# Are Temp Tables going to cause a huge log file problems when used for read-only report procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

So I've significantly reduced the execution time on two reports by using Temp tables. For each procedure, I create the temp table, insert into it, join on it, and then read the list. At the end of each procedure I manually drop this temp table.

I want to know if perhaps this sequence of events is being logged a whole lot somewhere and I'm going to cause a problem when these reports are viewed 100 times every week.

Again the procedures are read-only in as much as they edit no permanent tables so they don't need logging as far as I know. They're basically complicated select statements.

Comment: Temp tables are logged, but variable tables are not. So that's one option for you. However, I wouldn't worry about it from the start. Monitor the server for `tempdb` usage and then plan your next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would cause any issue, this is a very common and often recommended thing ... If you are paranoid :) you could always use a Table Variable

Comment: This is great to hear. I did attempt a Table Variable first. It is faster than no table but slower than Temp interestingly.